# Trying to use setNeedsDisplay()

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm trying to reload the UIView. Actually I get an error

> Cannot convert value of type 'HomeViewController' to expected argument type 'UIView'

So this is the code:

```
UIView.setNeedsDisplay(self)
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: `self.setNeedsDisplay()`?

Comment: @originaluser2 , not working. "Value of type 'HomeViewController' has no member 'setNeedsDisplay' "

Comment: ah, so you're in a `UIViewController`. So you want `self.view.setNeedsDisplay()`

Comment: @originaluser2 do you also know how to forecast the weather? :-) or future?

Comment: @user3441734 maybe if I put my mind to it ;)

Answer (score 5):

**`UIView` is a class, and `setNeedsDisplay()` is an instance function.**

You want to be calling this function on the `UIView` *instance* (not the class itself). So you want:

```
self.view.setNeedsDisplay();
```

`setNeedsDisplay()` also doesn't take any arguments, so I don't know why you were trying to pass `self` into it.

Comment: I'm trying to reload a bunch of code from viewDidAppear and I have no idea how should I do it. Actually, in viewDidAppear() I have the code: UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, .....). I want to change the time dynamically, then I have to reload somehow the view.. Any ideas?

Comment: "*I want to change the time dynamically*"... do you mean you want to input a variable into it? It doesn't sound like you're that sure on some important concepts. I think you should have a good read through the Apple docs on Swift, that should help you understand most of the key concepts: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309. If you still are unsure, feel free to ask another question.